# What is the meaning of {{Action [2], location: [3], command: [4] }} in WIX

Tags: wix

I had read a wix file. In that at the end of error they mentioned "{{Action [2], location: [3], command: [4] }}". What does it stands for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Formatted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368609.aspx). The `[2]` and so forth refer to fields in the record that's supplied for this message. A single set of curly braces means that the entire substring enclosed by them only remains if all properties or fields referenced inside are valid. I'm unclear what the double curly braces mean, though; the outer one may mean the inside is left unchanged, or it may not alter anything here.

When an error occurs and is reported, the reporter will create a record containing some number of fields with additional information. In the case of the one in the question, field 2 is expected to contain an action name, field 3 a location, and field 4 a command. For the example asked in the comment `{[2]}{, [3]}{, [4]}`, the record will be filled with some number of records. If only field 2 is filled, it will provide the entire formatted message (3 and 4 will be omitted). If fields 2 and 3 are filled, you will see the contents of field 2, a comma and a space, and the contents of field 3. The [error format strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372835.aspx) are intended to make things more understandable than

```
1: [ErrorNumber] 2: [SomeInfo] 3: [MoreInfo] 4: [Etc]
```

Comment: <Error Id="10">{[2]}{, [3]}{, [4]}</Error>  Can you explain what does it do?

Comment: These are strings used to format messages when errors occur. See also http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372835.aspx - if you search for Action there, you'll see `Action [2], location: [3], command: [4]` included in several messages.